# Pygame Moving image

Tags: python, pygame

Ive just started using pygame, I intend to make a platform game, however so far I cant get the sprite I made to move?

the code for the screen is in different files which have been imported   into this one

```
Vec = pygame.math.Vector2
VEL = Vec(0, 0)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0,0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 40

sprite = pygame.draw.circle(DS,WHITE,[500,250],20,10)
pygame.init()
class Sprite(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._image = sprite
        self._vx = 0
        self._vy = 0


    def update(self):
        self._vx = 0
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            self._vx = -5
        if key[K_LEFT]:
            self._vx = 5

        self._spritex = self._vx
        self._spritey = self._vy

Jumping = True
while Jumping:
        events()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                Jumping = False
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            sprite.left = sprite.left + PLAYER_ACC - 5
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            sprite.right = sprite.right + PLAYER_ACC + 5


            DS.fill(WHITE, sprite)


        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(FPS)
```

when this code is played it shows a white line that performs the movement not the actual circle i created, how could i get the circle to move?

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: you have to draw it inside `while Jumping`

Answer (score 1):

`draw.circle()` draws only once on screen and returns `Rect()` - object which only keeps position and size. It doesn't create object which will move when you change `sprite.x`, `sprite.y`.

---

Before `while` loop you can create `Rect()` to keep position

```
 sprite = pygame.Rect(500, 250, 0, 0)
```

and you can change `sprite.x`, `sprite.y` as before.

And inside `while` loop you have to use `draw.circle()` with `sprite.xy`

```
    DS.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.circle(DS, WHITE, sprite.topleft, 20, 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

BTW: it would be better to keep position as center in `Rect()` and set size as `2 * radius` - it means `2 * 20` - so you would use it with `colliderect()` to check collisions.

```
 sprite = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 2*20, 2*20)
 sprite.center = (500, 250)
```

and then you can use `sprite.center` to draw circle

```
    DS.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.circle(DS, WHITE, sprite.center, 20, 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

PyGame doc: [Rect](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however when i try the 1st bit you mentioned it came up with the error : line 57, in <module>
    SPRITE =  pygame.draw.circle(DS, WHITE, sprite.xy, 20, 10)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'xy'
will this mean I have to define sprite.xy before I call it into the draw.circle function?

Comment: sorry it is `sprite.topleft` - see other fields (ie. `sprite.center`) in link to `Rect`

Comment: BTW: to keep position and use in draw you can also use `pygame.math.Vector2` but you can't use it check collisions like with `pygame.Rect.colliderect()` (`sprite.colliderect()`)

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps want to create an instance of the `Sprite` class and then move it? Then you have to change the class a little bit and update and blit the sprite in the main loop.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
Vec = pygame.math.Vector2

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0,0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 40

# Create a surface/image and draw a circle onto it.
sprite_image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
pygame.draw.circle(sprite_image, WHITE, [25, 25], 20)


class Sprite(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        # Assign the global image to `self.image`.
        self.image = sprite_image
        # Create a rect which will be used as blit
        # position and for the collision detection.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Set the rect's center to the passed `pos`.
        self.rect.center = pos
        self._vx = 0
        self._vy = 0
        # Assign the pos also to these attributes.
        self._spritex = pos[0]
        self._spritey = pos[1]

    def update(self):
        self._vx = 0
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self._vx = 5
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self._vx = -5

        # Adjust the position.
        self._spritex += self._vx
        self._spritey += self._vy
        # And update the center of the rect.
        self.rect.center = (self._spritex, self._spritey)


# Create an instance of the Sprite class.
sprite = Sprite([200, 250])

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Call the `update` method of the sprite to move it.
    sprite.update()

    DS.fill(BLACK)
    # Blit the sprite's image at the sprite's rect.topleft position.
    DS.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank the both of you for your assistance, i got it to work both ways in the end

Comment: You're welcome! Also, we usually inherit from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13), then you can put the game objects into sprite groups, what makes it easy to update, draw and remove the sprites.